# Should a View contain the Model it present?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model

In MVC pattern, should a View contain the Model it is presenting?

For example, I have an Item model, ItemsListView & ItemRowView to display it.
In order to display the list, should I pass the Item model to ItemRowView (1) or I can pass Item.title, Item.details, Item.image, etc to the ItemRowView (2)

In (1), it is violate the MVC design pattern where View does not talk directly to the Model, and the View can also call Model methods

In (2), when make the View dummy, If in another ViewController, we use the ItemsList a gain, we have to duplicate the passing parameters again, and what happend if we need to pass one more properties to the user?

There another way, using ViewModel to wrap around the Model to handle UI Logic, but that will create many classes, and everytime I get a list of models, I also have to map it to ViewModels

example:

```
class ItemModel {
  var name: String = ""
  var price: Double = 9000
}
```

Should I assign the model to UITableViewCell like this: (so the cell can update the data itself whenever new data come)

```
class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

  var item: ItemModel! {
    didSet {
      self.updateUI()
    }
  }

  func updateUI() {
    titleLabel.text = item.name
  }
}
```

Or should I keep the cell dummy, and do the update UI in ViewController:

```
class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { 
  @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!   
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell: ItemTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemTableViewCell", for: indexPath)

  var item = items[indexPath.row]
  cell.titleLabel.text = item.name

  return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you give code examples ? I'm not sure I completely understand your examples ...

Comment: Hi, sorry for the question. I've updated

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As it enables you to use the base methods of the model itself instead of creating wrapper classes and handling conversion based on design change.

The Rule of thumb nowadays is to have a view-model for each view if that view requires more than one object.This allows you to handle design and data changes without touching the controller.